# Removing ungodly amount of conditional formatting

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have an excel file which has been in use for the last 2-3 years. It has been working well for the first 1.5 years until I added in conditional formatting.

So the problem (which regrettably I found out late) is that when moving (copy pasting rows) data, it breaks my conditional formatting to small ranges.

Now, everyday, I probably move close to 5-6 rows everyday and it adds ups.

So right now, I have such an ungodly amount of conditional formatting that just inserting rows take 15mins.

I tried clearing the conditional formatting as per the steps here: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/938-excel-remove-conditional-formatting.html

But it takes incredibly long... It still running by the way and has been running for 5 hrs.

Was wondering if there are better alternatives I could use?

Thanks!

Comment: Which option did you use?

Comment: I tried the vba method and the clear rules method

Comment: Hi, just a follow up, I left my PC running overnight and it has completed the removal of conditional formatting. I also made a vba code to prevent that from ever happening again... But I am still open to ideas of removing these conditional formatting in a much quicker method

Comment: Someone [in this microsoft question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/paste-formatting-without-conditional-formatting/c8dd0276-076a-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5) mentioned saving it as a webpage and then saving it back as a workbook, saving the formatting but not the conditional formatting.